# Best Approach to deploying multiple Web Parts

Tags: web-part

What is the best approach to deploying multiple web parts?

- Create one Visual Studio solution and
  add all the web parts as separate
  SPIs?

The thing about this approach is when one change is made to one web part, all web parts get updated since they are compiled into one dll.

- Or, create a separate solution for
  each web part, which in turn gives us
  a seperate dlls.

But do I really want 20 solutions to manage for the 20 individual web parts?

- Or individual Features?

...

I'm after advantages and disadvantages of each approach. (All web parts will have the same level of security and the dlls can be placed in the GAC.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a combination. One solution for all your web parts, one project for each solution.

This way, each webpart has it's own DLL.

use WSPBuilder to package up the web part DLLs into a single solution which can be deployed at once.

The thing about needing to update a single webpart then needing to update the entire DLL (if you do all in one) is a common issue, and you'll just have to keep on top of change management, ensure that everyone involed knows the full implications of changes to web part DLLs and that only relevant and priority changes go through.